# Python Recursion List ( pop vs [ ] )

Tags: python, list, recursion

I am working on recursion and I have a problem that I have solved but I would like to know what is going on and why the way I tried first does not work. The only issue I have is emptying the listOfX when it has a length of 3.

Here is the original code that does not work as expected:

```
sol = []
def recLoop(levelWidth,levelOn,listOfX):
    if len(listOfX) == 3:
        sol.append([listOfX[0],listOfX[1]])
        sol.append([listOfX[0],listOfX[2]])
        listOfX = []     #THIS DOES NOT WORK

    print listOfX
    if len(levelWidth) != levelOn: 
        for x in range(levelWidth[levelOn]):
            listOfX.append(x)
            recLoop(levelWidth,levelOn+1,listOfX)

recLoop([3,2],0,[])
print sol
```

However it works as expected when I use `pop()` instead like this:

```
sol = []
def recLoop(levelWidth,levelOn,listOfX):
    if len(listOfX) == 3:
        sol.append([listOfX[0],listOfX[1]])
        sol.append([listOfX[0],listOfX[2]])
        listOfX.pop()
        listOfX.pop()
        listOfX.pop()

    print listOfX
    if len(levelWidth) != levelOn: 
        for x in range(levelWidth[levelOn]):
            listOfX.append(x)
            recLoop(levelWidth,levelOn+1,listOfX)

recLoop([3,2],0,[])
print sol
```

NOTE: the outcome of the first code is:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1]]
```

but it should be:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1], [2, 0], [2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement:

```
listOfX = []
```

simply rebinds the local variable (which is just a reference to an object) to a new list. The original list object is still referenced elsewhere but not affected by this rebinding. Using `listOfX.pop()` on the other hand directly manipulates that object.

You can use:

```
listOfX[:] = []
```

to clear the list, instead.